# Sending multiple emails with a foreach loop

Tags: php

I am trying to send multiple emails via a for loop so I don't have to worry about hiding all the other emails but every time I test it, It keeps send the the last email in the array and total misses the first and last names.

Here is how the each array element reads "firstname lastname <email>," (the quotes are just to seperate it from the sentence)

Here's the code:

```
$to = $_POST['to'];
$from = "$sender";
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$i = "";
if($to == "Mass email"){
    $sql =("SELECT * FROM `$table5`");
    $res = mysqli_query($con5, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());

    $adresses = [];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $email = $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . " &#60;" .    $row['email'] . "&#62;";
        $adresses[] = $email;
    }

    foreach($adresses as $value){
        if(empty($_FILES['file'])){
            $mbox = imap_open("{mail.server.com:993/novalidate-cert/imap/ssl}", "$eun", "$epw");
            $sent_mass_1 = mail($value, $subject, $message, "From: $from");
            if($sent_mass_1){
                    imap_append($mbox, "{mail.server.com:993/novalidate-cert/imap/ssl}INBOX.Sent"
                    , "Date: $date\r\n"
                    . "To: " . $value . "\r\n"
                    . "From: $from\r\n"
                    . "Subject: $subject\r\n"
                    . "\r\n"
                    . "$message\r\n"
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm just getting started in php arrays and I have a lot more to learn

Comment: `print_r($adresses);` just after the while. Is everything shown?

Comment: When using print_r, all the address show up as the should. Array([0] => firstname lastname <email>, [1] => firname lastname <email> etc.... When I implament the foreach loop, all I get is <email> of the last entry in the array and it will be sent however many times there are items in the array as per the foreach loop should word. But, I don't get all the data the way I should

Comment: I looped through all the data in the email header. I got firstname@MISSING_DOMAIN when I try to get the To: in the email header.

Comment: I fixed the error with only getting the last email in the array. I get the whole email address when I echo each of the element in the array in a foreach loop. I tried using the htmlspecialchars function for the < and > that encapsulate the email, but the mail function does not work I tried it on my local server and it works just fine but not on godaddy servers